# Run Different Scikit-learn Clustering Algorithms on Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe like below. The shape is (24,7)

```
Name   x1   x2   x3    x4    x5    x6
Harry  102  204  0.43  0.21  1.02  0.39
James  242  500  0.31  0.11  0.03  0.73
.
.
.
Mike   3555 4002 0.12  0.03  0.52. 0.11
Henry  532  643  0.01  0.02  0.33  0.10
```

I want to run Scikit-learn's Different Clustering Algorithms Script on the above dataframe. However, the input data looks quite confusing, not too sure how to input my dataframe

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-cluster-comparison-py

Comment: What do you want to try ? just different cluster algo ?

Comment: Yep, exactly that

Comment: Do you understand that they give different data, and apply different algorithms of clusterings to show you the difference. This is purely to show you the differents algorithms with different types of data

Comment: Ah, couldnt understand that. How do I apply different algorithms of clusterings to on the same dataset (ie for my dataframe above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main differences between your scenario and the scikit-learn example you link to:

1. You only have one dataset, not several different ones to compare.
2. You have six features, not just two.

Point one allows you to simplify the example code by deleting the loops over the different datasets and related calculations. Point two implies that you cannot easily plot your results. Instead, you could just add the predicted class labels found by each algorithm to your dataset.

So you could modify the example code like this:

```py
import time
import warnings

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn import cluster, datasets, mixture
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from itertools import cycle, islice

np.random.seed(0)

# ============
# Introduce your dataset
# ============
my_df =  # Insert your data here, as a pandas dataframe. 
features = [f'x{i}' for i in range(1, 7)]
X = my_df[features].values

# ============
# Set up cluster parameters
# ============
params = {
    "quantile": 0.3,
    "eps": 0.3,
    "damping": 0.9,
    "preference": -200,
    "n_neighbors": 3,
    "n_clusters": 3,
    "min_samples": 7,
    "xi": 0.05,
    "min_cluster_size": 0.1,
}

# normalize dataset for easier parameter selection
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

# estimate bandwidth for mean shift
bandwidth = max(cluster.estimate_bandwidth(X, quantile=params["quantile"]),
                0.001)  # arbitrary correction to avoid 0

# connectivity matrix for structured Ward
connectivity = kneighbors_graph(
    X, n_neighbors=params["n_neighbors"], include_self=False
)
# make connectivity symmetric
connectivity = 0.5 * (connectivity + connectivity.T)

# ============
# Create cluster objects
# ============
ms = cluster.MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
two_means = cluster.MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=params["n_clusters"])
ward = cluster.AgglomerativeClustering(
    n_clusters=params["n_clusters"], linkage="ward", connectivity=connectivity
)
spectral = cluster.SpectralClustering(
    n_clusters=params["n_clusters"],
    eigen_solver="arpack",
    affinity="nearest_neighbors",
)
dbscan = cluster.DBSCAN(eps=params["eps"])
optics = cluster.OPTICS(
    min_samples=params["min_samples"],
    xi=params["xi"],
    min_cluster_size=params["min_cluster_size"],
)
affinity_propagation = cluster.AffinityPropagation(
    damping=params["damping"], preference=params["preference"], random_state=0
)
average_linkage = cluster.AgglomerativeClustering(
    linkage="average",
    affinity="cityblock",
    n_clusters=params["n_clusters"],
    connectivity=connectivity,
)
birch = cluster.Birch(n_clusters=params["n_clusters"])
gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(
    n_components=params["n_clusters"], covariance_type="full"
)

clustering_algorithms = (
    ("MiniBatch\nKMeans", two_means),
    ("Affinity\nPropagation", affinity_propagation),
    ("MeanShift", ms),
    ("Spectral\nClustering", spectral),
    ("Ward", ward),
    ("Agglomerative\nClustering", average_linkage),
    ("DBSCAN", dbscan),
    ("OPTICS", optics),
    ("BIRCH", birch),
    ("Gaussian\nMixture", gmm),
)

for name, algorithm in clustering_algorithms:
    t0 = time.time()

    # catch warnings related to kneighbors_graph
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.filterwarnings(
            "ignore",
            message="the number of connected components of the "
            + "connectivity matrix is [0-9]{1,2}"
            + " > 1. Completing it to avoid stopping the tree early.",
            category=UserWarning,
        )
        warnings.filterwarnings(
            "ignore",
            message="Graph is not fully connected, spectral embedding"
            + " may not work as expected.",
            category=UserWarning,
        )
        algorithm.fit(X)

    t1 = time.time()
    if hasattr(algorithm, "labels_"):
        y_pred = algorithm.labels_.astype(int)
    else:
        y_pred = algorithm.predict(X)

    # Add cluster labels to the dataset
    my_df[name] = y_pred
```

Comment: Cool, this one predicted the clusters well! How can I visualise this?

Comment: It's difficult to visualize the cluster labels and all six features at once. For similar scatterplots to the ones in the scikit-learn example, you could either just pick two of the features for each plot, or run a dimensionality reduction algorithm first, e.g. principal component analysis, which is also available in scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

PS : please replace : data = X_data.iloc[:20000] by your X

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import cluster, metrics
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, fcluster
from sklearn import preprocessing
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import mixture
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score

comp_model = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Model', 'Score_Silhouette',
                                   'num_clusters', 'size_clusters',
                                   'parameters'])
```

K-Means :

```
def k_means(X_data, nb_clusters, model_comp):

    ks = nb_clusters
    inertias = []
    data = X_data.iloc[:20000]
    X = data.values
    X_scaled = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

    for num_clusters in ks:
        # Create a KMeans instance with k clusters: model
        model = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, n_init=1)

        # Fit model to samples
        model.fit(X_scaled)

        # Append the inertia to the list of inertias
        inertias.append(model.inertia_)

        silh = metrics.silhouette_score(X_scaled, model.labels_)

        # Counting the amount of data in each cluster
        taille_clusters = Counter(model.labels_)

        data = [{'Model': 'kMeans',
                 'Score_Silhouette': silh,
                 'num_clusters': num_clusters,
                 'size_clusters': taille_clusters,
                 'parameters': 'nb_clusters :'+str(num_clusters)}]

        model_comp = model_comp.append(data, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

    # Plot ks vs inertias
    plt.plot(ks, inertias, '-o')
    plt.xlabel('number of clusters, k')
    plt.ylabel('inertia')
    plt.xticks(ks)
    plt.show()
    return model_comp

comp_model = k_means(X_data=df,
                     nb_clusters=pd.np.arange(2, 11, 1),
                     model_comp=comp_model)
```

DBscan :

```
def dbscan_grid_search(X_data, model_comp, eps_space=0.5,
                       min_samples_space=5, min_clust=0, max_clust=10):

    data = X_data.iloc[:20000]
    X = data.values
    X_scaled = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

    # Starting a tally of total iterations
    n_iterations = 0

    # Looping over each combination of hyperparameters
    for eps_val in eps_space:
        for samples_val in min_samples_space:

            dbscan_grid = DBSCAN(eps=eps_val,
                                 min_samples=samples_val)

            # fit_transform
            clusters = dbscan_grid.fit_predict(X=X_scaled)

            # Counting the amount of data in each cluster
            cluster_count = Counter(clusters)

            #n_clusters = sum(abs(pd.np.unique(clusters))) - 1
            n_clusters = len(set(clusters)) - (1 if -1 in clusters else 0)

            # Increasing the iteration tally with each run of the loop
            n_iterations += 1

            # Appending the lst each time n_clusters criteria is reached
            if n_clusters >= min_clust and n_clusters <= max_clust:

                silh = metrics.silhouette_score(X_scaled, clusters)

                data = [{'Model': 'Dbscan',
                         'Score_Silhouette': silh,
                         'num_clusters': n_clusters,
                         'size_clusters': cluster_count,
                         'parameters': 'eps :'+str(eps_val)+'+ samples_val :'+str(samples_val)}]

                model_comp = model_comp.append(
                    data, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

    return model_comp
comp_model = dbscan_grid_search(X_data=df,
                                model_comp=comp_model,
                                eps_space=pd.np.arange(0.1, 5, 0.6),
                                min_samples_space=pd.np.arange(1, 30, 3),
                                min_clust=2,
                                max_clust=10)
```

GMM :

```
def gmm(X_data, nb_clusters, model_comp):

    ks = nb_clusters
    data = X_data.iloc[:20000]
    X = data.values
    X_scaled = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

    for num_clusters in ks:
        # Create a KMeans instance with k clusters: model
        gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=num_clusters).fit(X_scaled)

        # Fit model to samples
        gmm.fit(X_scaled)
        pred = gmm.predict(X_scaled)

        cluster_count = Counter(pred)

        silh = metrics.silhouette_score(X_scaled, pred)

        data = [{'Model': 'GMM',
                 'Score_Silhouette': silh,
                 'num_clusters': num_clusters,
                 'size_clusters': cluster_count,
                 'parameters': 'nb_clusters :'+str(num_clusters)}]

        model_comp = model_comp.append(data, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

    return model_comp

comp_model = gmm(X_data=df,
                 nb_clusters=pd.np.arange(2, 11, 1),
                 model_comp=comp_model
                 )
```

At the end you will have comp_model which will contain all the results of your algo. Here I am using three algorithms, after you selected the best fit for you (with score silhouette and number of cluster).

You should check the repartitions of each cluster :
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-kmeans-silhouette-analysis-py

Comment: How do I produce the figure for all these algorithms shown? i.e for:

MiniBatch, KMeans, Affinity Propagation, MeanShift, Spectral Clustering, spectral, Ward, Agglomerative Clustering, DBSCAN, OPTICS, BIRCH, Gaussian Mixture. 

Basically trying to reproduce that plot for my dataframe

Comment: @user341383 you can use this link : https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/plot-k-means-clusters-python I recommend you to use, a metric instead of some visualization of each clusters on a plot

Comment: Cool, I've done this. However, how could I visualize this? Would I need to use some sort of dimensionality reduction? If yes, how I go about it?

Comment: @user341383 sorry did not understand what you want to do ?

Comment: are you able to produce a visualization of Arne's solution?